# How to access site when I am already login selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to run my tests when I am logged in already
Every time when I run the URL its ask me to log in again (When I make it handy its OK).

Is there any way to pass this stage of login ?
Any way with token or something else ?

Thanks

Comment: With the limited knowledge that I have: Whenever you login, a session is created and it would expire when the driver is quit/closed, and hence every time you run the tests, it opens a new session - and everything is brand new to a new session - so, it goes to login again. Either you should keep the session open for all tests or you should have an API that keeps you logged in from the background and if you have any such, you can pass it into your code.

Comment: Thanks - I need something more specific to solve it